# Multiple sites with independent users

Tags: multisite

I've been going round and round with this so I hope someone can help!

I've setup about 10 websites, all on Wordpress, for friends. At the moment, each of these sites are on separate wordpress installs. What i'd like to do is get to the stage where I have 1 install that can accomodate the 10 sites, but each site can't see the details/users/themes etc. of the other sites.

Here is what i've tried so far:

1. WP-Hive - This appeared to have some potential however it only caters to a single administrator. As i've just done these sites for friends, I generally give them a login to get in and edit the page content/post blogs themselves. So I don't think this will work.
2. Wordpress 3.0.3 Network - I set this up with 2 sites however I had trouble with the domains and redirects as well as the level of access users had to everything (ie. Users can see all of the themes and plugins available, even when they aren't relevant to them).

The last thing i've found to try is this: http://striderweb.com/nerdaphernalia/features/virtual-multiblog/

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can get this to work?

Comment: accomodate is accommodate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 should work, I just wrote http://wp.leau.co/2010/12/24/moving-a-weblog-to-a-wp3-multisite-weblog-system-on-mediatemple/

- themes: you should NOT network activate all themes, only activate them on a specific site via the site settings for a blog
- plugins: disable the setting in the network admin to display plugin etc..

### How to enable a theme for a specific site

*To network-enable or to not network-enable, that's the question!*

**1** click on network admin

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb4.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb4.png)

**2** click on themes

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb5.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb5.png)

**3**. Add your themes and make sure it says “network Enable” (so do NOT network enable them) (since then they would be available for all sites)

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb6.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb6.png)

**4**. click on sites

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb7.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb7.png)

**5** Click on “edit” beneath the site you want to give access to a theme (or a plugin)

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb8.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb8.png)

**6** Click on the tab “Themes” and find the theme you want to activate, then press “enable” beneath that theme.

[image http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb9.png](http://wp.leau.co/files/2010/12/image_thumb9.png)

**7** You are done, the theme is now available for that blog.

Comment: @edelwater - Can you elaborate on how to activate a theme for a specific site? Screenshots and source code would be awesome...! :)

Comment: done, i have added it to the answer but I think.... there must be a gazillion weblog postings out there also

Comment: @mike once again, I worte a post (with screenshots) on how to enable themes for just one site ageas ago. ;) 
http://wpmututorials.com/themes/enabling-a-theme-for-just-one-blog/

Comment: @edelwater - Thanks! Can I suggest one change?  Step six says *"Click on the "themes" tab"*; that was confusing for me. Would it not be more correct to say *"Find the "Site Themes" Metabox?"*

Comment: @andrea_r - Thanks! One thing though, I didn't see any screenshots?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Metabox? On my 3.1 it IS actually a tab?

Comment: @edelwater - Awesome update. BTW, you might want to caveat and say if not using v3.1 yet _(which few people currently are)_ then it'll be a metabox and not a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just o make sure you get my post above, http://wpmututorials.com/themes/enabling-a-theme-for-just-one-blog/

there's also a plugin to help lock down what plugins are available to each site.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-multisite-widgets/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-multisite-plugins/

Really, setting up a network is the way to go. you're setting up your own version of wordpress.com for your buddies.

If you want separate domains, use the domain mapping plugin. No redirects needed.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/
http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Comment: Ok great. For some reason when I was doing it today it didn't seem that easy but I will try again!!